# Explaination on this "more accurate implementation" of Gradient magnitude thresholding

Tags: canny-edge-detector

I'm reading the implementation of "Canny edge detector" in Wiki page: [Canny edge detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector). In the section "Gradient magnitude thresholding", it says:

> In more accurate implementations, linear interpolation is used between
> the two neighbouring pixels that straddle the gradient direction. For
> example, if the gradient angle is between 89° and 180°, interpolation
> between gradients at the north and north-east pixels will give one
> interpolated value, and interpolation between the south and south-west
> pixels will give the other (using the conventions of the last
> paragraph). The gradient magnitude at the central pixel must be
> greater than both of these for it to be marked as an edge.

If I understand correctly, it basically states that instead of rounding angles to "0, 45, 90, 135, 180" to account for neighboring directions, we use interpolated values when angles between two values. Then why use the range "89 to 180" for "(north, north-east) and (south, south-west)"? Why is it not something like "0 to 45 for "(east, north-east) and (west, south-west)" and "45 to 90 for (north, north-east) and (south, south-west)" and so on? Hope you help me clarify this.